# Java implementation of Supersingular isogeny Diffie–Hellman key exchange (SIDH)

Tags: open-source, library, java, cryptography

I am looking for a [SIDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_key_exchange) implementation for Java.

Any license, it's for testing.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Do you need the ability to see the source code? Or is an opaque JAR OK?

Comment: Source code is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one, as of this posting. The [best available](https://github.com/Microsoft/PQCrypto-SIDH) implementations of SIDH are in C and there are some others of academic quality (read, not for production) in Sage/Python.

Answer (score 1):

A Java implementation is now available at https://github.com/Art3misOne/sidh.

Answer (score 1):

You can try our library: https://github.com/wultra/sike-java

It implements both SIDH and SIKE and is linked from https://sike.org as a third-party implementation.